# Select with a variable of a procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures

Is it possible to make a select with the result of another select within a stored procedure?

I have this stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spRelacaoVendas]
    @usuario nvarchar(60) = NULL,
    @dataEmissao datetime,
    @dataSaida datetime
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        NF.ID AS ID, NF.NaturezaOperacao AS Natureza, 
        NF.DataEmissao AS Data, NF.ValorTotal AS ValorTotal
    FROM
        NotaFiscal NF 
    INNER JOIN
        Venda V ON NF.ID_Venda = V.ID 
    INNER JOIN
        Usuario U ON V.ID_UsuarioComissao1 = U.ID
    WHERE
        ((U.Descricao = @usuario) OR (@usuario IS NULL)) AND
        (NF.DataEmissao >= @dataEmissao AND NF.DataSaida <= @dataSaida)
END
```

I would like to make another select with the ID resulting from that select, within the same stored procedure, is this possible?

Comment: You can assign it to a variable, just not in the same select statement as the one returning values, so you'll have to duplicate the select.

Comment: Each statement is independent of another. You can't reference a prior result set in a later `SELECT`. If you need to retain the data, would would need to store it in something, such as a variable or (temporary) table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'm understanding this right.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spRelacaoVendas]
    @usuario nvarchar(60) = NULL,
    @dataEmissao datetime,
    @dataSaida datetime
AS
BEGIN
    select
        *
    FROM
        (SELECT NF.ID AS ID, NF.NaturezaOperacao AS Natureza, NF.DataEmissao AS Data, NF.ValorTotal AS ValorTotal
        FROM NotaFiscal NF INNER JOIN
            Venda V
        ON NF.ID_Venda = V.ID INNER JOIN
            Usuario U 
        ON V.ID_UsuarioComissao1 = U.ID
        WHERE
            ((U.Descricao = @usuario) OR (@usuario IS NULL)) AND
            (NF.DataEmissao >= @dataEmissao AND NF.DataSaida <= @dataSaida)) temp
END
```

Basically, I put the first select inside of parenthesis then aliased it, sort of making it a virtual table. I did `select *`, but you can select any of the results from the embedded query.

Comment: I can use the result ID of temp in another select ?

Comment: You sure can, you can even join other tables onto temp

Answer (score 1):

You can save the result in a temporary table and then do with it whatever you like:

```
SELECT NF.ID AS ID, NF.NaturezaOperacao AS Natureza, NF.DataEmissao AS Data, NF.ValorTotal AS ValorTotal
INTO #Nota
. . .;
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, as long as it is encapsulated to avoid certain errors and easy to maintain.

Comment: I don't know what that is, but it isn't an answer to the question.

Comment: Do you mean the returned value of stored procedure?